# use function from html script

Tags: javascript, html, url

I'm perplex. I think I know what's wrong, but I can not seem to figure out what the correction is.

I have several external URL scripts, that load in the HTML file, via `<script type="text/javascript src="https://the/path/root.js"></script>`

This should make the all the function contained WITHIN that root.js available to ALL the files listed in the `<head>` or only the html.

so if I'm a myFile.js and I make a function call that's within root.js it does nothing. and nothing is executed.

so myFile.html

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript> src="https://some/path/name/root.js>
    </script>
</head>
```

and myJS.js

```
function root();(which is not declared or defined in the myJS.js file, but is located in the root.js file of the URL).
```

How do I reference it? can I take the script right out, and put it directly into the myJS.js, are there scripts that are HTML dependendent?

its for a school assignment. If anyone can help out...really appreciate it.

Also, if I'm in the HTML, and I want to load functions from that JS file, i tried `<body onload="root();">` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you look in the network panel in your developer console, do you see a 404? The markup above is wrong, is it a typo? Are there errors in your console...

Comment: You would load root.js, then myfile.js (in that order) using script tags.  myfile.js should *call* root(), not redefine it (with the keyword function).

Comment: Please, try to cleanup your question, it's really difficult to understand your real problem. Remember that SO users won't be able to see your errors. Write your post and try to expose a single and straight question.

Comment: Hey Everyone, I got an update for you all, thank you all for answering me. The reason I asked the question, was because something was functioning. It appeared as if 2 scripts were colliding. However, I have since done more research, and 1 of the scripts is only available and functional when on a HTTPS server, as it utilizes a google api. So it can't be run from a local machine. (i didn't know until after I asked the question, as I didn't even think this was a consideration, but apparently it is. ) thank you all again for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is a little messed up, but if I'm understanding correctly, if you have a function like this in `root.js`:

```
function root() { console.log('do something'); }
```

And you want to use it in `myJS.js`, you wouldn't use:

```
function root(); // this is a syntax error
```

Instead, you would just use it like you would a function defined in the same file:

```
root();
```

The other key is you have to make sure that you are loading the `root.js` file before `myJS.js` (order matters):

```
<head>
  <script src="http://example.com/path/to/root.js"></script>
  <script src="http://example.com/path/to/myJS.js"></script>
</head>
```

Beyond that, just make sure you have the correct file path to each. You can make sure by using the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools (or similar in other browsers).

For:

```
<body onload="root()">
```

That should work, as long as the function is actually there.

Check the developer console for any other errors that may be coming up that may be confusing the situation as well. Also, make sure your scripts are in the `<head>` before the `<body>`.

Comment: assumption based answering, I appreciate your effort :) brave SO user ;)